# How to use a -Manifest package in Pharo Smalltalk after File-in/Install?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I just upgraded to the newest version of Pharo Smalltalk.  Before doing so, I "File-outed" a package from my old version called **My-Pharo** - a package I use for various configurations and customizations of Pharo itself, most notably a class to put back "Workspace" in the main menu.  I then "File-ined/Installed" the file into my new version.

When I checked the SystemBrowser, I had correctly gotten the **My-Pharo** package, but I'd also picked up a package called **My-Pharo-Manifest**...  I see **My-Pharo-Manifest** actually is part of my File-Out, and seems to contain the package-comment for **My-Pharo** .

What *is* this manifest, what is it's purpose, and how should it be used?  Is there something I can/should do to "merge" the manifest (ie. the comment) back into the **My-Pharo** class?  Should I move the content of **My-Pharo-Manifest** somewhere else?  ...Or is my best bet to simply delete the Manifest-package, and re-write the package-comment for **My-Pharo**?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a seasoned Pharo developer, I use it just time to time.  I'll try to answer your question from the source code.  For more detailed answer you would have to get it from the ones that are actually do the development of Pharo.

> What is manifest?

Manifest contains package metadata.

> what is it's purpose?

The purpose is to make life easier for the `SmallLint` (Smalltalk Code Critics).  It is there for its speedup, because without the *manifest* the `SmallLint` would have to check the rule results all the time.  Package metadata helps in managing false positives and/or TODOs.

- packages: If you check for the where is the `#hasPackageNamed:` used, you will find out that it is at `SmallLintManifestChecker>>manifestBuilderOfPackage:`.
- methods: if you search for `#hasManifestFor:` `SmallLintManifestChecker>>manifestBuilderOfMethod:`

> Is there something I can/should do to "merge" the manifest (ie. the
> comment) back into the My-Pharo class? Should I move the content of
> My-Pharo-Manifest somewhere else?

I would just leave it be.  It helps the `SmallLint` to do its job.